# BAPI for reading CCMS values

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-basis

I am currently developing a small application which reads actual values from the CCMS Monitoring, but I got a small problem.

I actually use the BAPI `BAPI_SYSTEM_MTE_GETPERFCURVAL` to read the values from the CCMS environment (e.g CPU_Utilisation).

But for some values this is not working. A collegue told me to use `BAPI_SYSTEM_MTE_GETMLCURVAL`.

But this one is also not working for all CCMS Items (eg. it is not working for CPU_Utilisation).

Is there a BAPI which can read all CCMS values? It would be great if there was a BAPI which had the same input parameters as the ones above.

PS: (Yes, I know in the near future there will be a new monitoring environment (MAI))

[EDIT]

Hi,

I figured something out.

Each CCMS Object has a [type](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/6a/c7453bafc6007ce10000000a11402f/content.htm). (performance, logging, alerting)

I know, that the BAPI `BAPI_SYSTEM_MTE_GETTIDBYNAME` delivers me the parameter `TID` for the given `MTE-OBJECT-NAME` tuple. Inside the `TID` is a field which is called `MTCLASS`.

Can anybody tell me, where I can find the values for the field `MTCLASS` so that I can decide whether to use `BAPI_SYSTEM_MTE_GETPERFCURVAL` or `BAPI_SYSTEM_MTE_GETMLCURVAL`?

Comment: Thanks for the remark on MAI (didn't know that there is new stuff in preparation)

Comment: Can't you use them both? If the second does not give you the CPU utilization, then simply read those values with the first one and all the others with the second one.

Comment: @Jagger This might be the solution. I figured out, that there are different types of values inside CCMS. So I have to use both BAPI. The only thing I need to do is, figure out of which type my CCMS value is. I hope to find there a BAPI as well.

Comment: added some new informations to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question from the edited part...

The possible values for the `MTCLASS` are defined as constants in the include `RSALBAPI`.

Here comes a fragment of this include with aforementioned constants.

```
* monitoring tree element (MT): type classes
CONSTANTS:
  MT_CLASS_NO_CLASS     LIKE  ALGLOBTID-MTCLASS       VALUE '000',
  MT_CLASS_SUMMARY      LIKE  ALGLOBTID-MTCLASS       VALUE '050',
  MT_CLASS_MONIOBJECT   LIKE  ALGLOBTID-MTCLASS       VALUE '070',
  MT_CLASS_FIRST_MA     LIKE  ALGLOBTID-MTCLASS       VALUE '099',
  MT_CLASS_PERFORMANCE  LIKE  ALGLOBTID-MTCLASS       VALUE '100',
  MT_CLASS_MSG_CONT     LIKE  ALGLOBTID-MTCLASS       VALUE '101',
  MT_CLASS_SINGLE_MSG   LIKE  ALGLOBTID-MTCLASS       VALUE '102',
  MT_CLASS_HEARTBEAT    LIKE  ALGLOBTID-MTCLASS       VALUE '103',
  MT_CLASS_LONGTEXT     LIKE  ALGLOBTID-MTCLASS       VALUE '110',
  MT_CLASS_SHORTTEXT    LIKE  ALGLOBTID-MTCLASS       VALUE '111',
  MT_CLASS_VIRTUAL      LIKE  ALGLOBTID-MTCLASS       VALUE '199'.
```